# How to convert complex sed commands to a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, sed

I have a Windows batch file the uses `sed` to manipulate files. The manipulation includes simple substitutions like

```
sed -e s/PATTERN/OTHERS/g                 infile >outfile
sed -e "/^.*COPY_START/,/^.*COPY_END/ d"  infile >outfile
```

While the first one can be replaced by

```
Get-Content infile | %{ $_ -replace 'PATTERN', 'OTHERS' } | Set-Content outfile
```

I didn't found how to select a bunch of lines that shall be removed by the line markers `COPY_START` and `COPY_END`.

How can these `sed` commands be replaced with PowerShell.

**Edit:** Regarding Jeff's comment I tried to catch the multi-line problem with this code:

```
Get-Content infile -replace '(.*)COPY_START\n.*COPY_END(.*)','$1$2'
```

But the `\n` does not fulfill the search criteria. To isolate the "multi-line" criteria I used

```
Get-Content infile -match 'COPY_START\n.*COPY_END'
```

with this file

```
before
do COPY_START
skip
until COPY_END
after
```

But the match is always `$False`. I expected that the expression `\n.*` should match with the line end after COPY_START and all lines until COPY_END appears.

Why doesn't match the regular expression and how can I fix it?

Comment: I commend to your attention the [Microsoft documentation on Regular Expressions in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Use `Get-Content -Raw` to read the whole file in, not read it line by line. Else, you can't match anything with a pattern having `\n` in it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for pointer. Unfortunately `(get-content -raw foo.txt )  -match "START"` results to `True` but `(get-content -raw foo.txt )  -match "START\n.*END" results to `False`. So reading the file into _one_ line doesn't help.

Comment: But you must have `\r\n` endings, why do you only use `\n`?

Comment: Your match criteria should be `-cmatch "(?s)COPY_START\r?\n.*COPY_END\r?\n"`

Comment: @AdminOfThings This doesn't match the text in the example file. You need an additional `.*\n ` to get the line `skip`. But it's not the intention of the script to predict the number of lines to skip.

Comment: I copied your text into a single-line string. The match worked. The (?s) modifier forces . to match newline characters.

Comment: Ouch. I missed the `(?s)` in front.

Comment: I think you want `(get-content -raw foo.txt )  -replace "(?m)^.*COPY_START(?s:.*?)COPY_END.*$\n?"` is what your second `sed` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sed -e "/^.*COPY_START/,/^.*COPY_END/ d"  infile >outfile` command finds all substrings between lines having `COPY_START` and `COPY_END` and removes them from the `infile` and saves the output to `outfile`.

To make it work in PS, you need to read the file into a single variables with `-Raw` and use a regex like

```
(?m)^.*COPY_START(?s:.*?)COPY_END.*$\n?
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E.*COPY_START%28%3Fs%3A.*%3F%29COPY_END.*%24%5Cn%3F&i=before%0D%0Ado%20COPY_START%0D%0Askip%0D%0Auntil%20COPY_END%0D%0Aafter&r=).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - a MULTILINE inline modifier, `^` will match the start of a line now
- `^` - line start
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than LF, as many as possible
- `COPY_START`  - a substring
- `(?s:.*?)` - an inline modifier group (where `s` enables the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option, also known as DOTALL, when `.` matches any char) that matches any 0+ chars, as few as possible up to the first
- `COPY_END.*$` - `COPY_END` and then any 0+ chars other than a newline as many as possible
- `\n?` - and an optional newline.

Comment: Nice one (+1) I didn't recognize the inline modifiers could be used inside a non capturing group to limit the scope of the modifier.