# Regexp match and replace or delete multiple lines of text in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have to use power shell to delete block of text with known first and last line. How I should do it?

First I tried to match whole text block first and it worked... until somebody changed middle lines. Now I am trying to use some sort of regexp.
This block will always start with line "# START" and end with line "# STOP".

I write standard regexp wchich is maching desired text, I used https://regexr.com/ to test it.

```bsh
    (Get-Content .\file.conf -Raw) | % {
        $_ -replace "# START(.*\n)*# STOP", ''
    } | Set-Content .\file.conf
```

When I try to use it form powershell in a way shown above it doesn't match anything and I have no idea why. 
Is there any better solution to my problem?

Here is example file content.

````
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
# Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

# START
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
# Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

# STOP

# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ```
````

Comment: could you provide Input file pls?

Comment: I just added example file which is also meeting conditions of my case and matching in regexr.com

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56545311/6811411) posted just one hour ago

Comment: It's working here. Try to use a different filename for Output.

Comment: Depending on your line endings I'd try: `(Get-Content .\file.conf -Raw) | % {$_ -replace '\r?\n# START(.*\r?\n)*# STOP\r?\n'}` using single quotes and optional CR `\r?`

Answer (score 0):

As per your example text the regEx should be like this :

> ```
> $file = "C:\PowershellScripts\test.txt"    
> $data = Get-Content $file -Raw    
> $data -replace "# START[\r\n\#\,\.\sA-Za-z]*# STOP",""
> ```